Show $x^p-x$ is not in $\ker\Psi_p$
Let $p\in\mathbb{P}$ be a prime integer.
Let $\Psi_p:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ be the homomorphism of reduction mod $p$. Show that the polynomial $x^p-x\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not in $\ker\Psi_p$ but all the evaluations of $\Psi_p(x^p-x)\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ are null.

I don't have a proof yet but I was trying to analyze this concrete example:
$P(x)=x^2+x+2\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The reduction mod $2$ of $P$ is $x^2+x\in\mathbb{F}_2$ and clearly $x^2+x=x(x+1).$ Notice that the evaluations of this polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2$ are null: $$0(0+1)=0\cdot1=0,$$
and $$ 1(1+1)=1\cdot 0=0$$
Any hints on how to prove this exercise

There is not much to prove... show that the image of $x^p-x$ modulo $p$ is not the zero polynomial... which is easy. Then show that the polynomial function that the polynomial defines is the zero function, using Fermat's Little Theorem.

It is obviously not in the kernel by looking at the coefficients of the polynomial.
To prove that all evaluations are $0$, use Lagrange's theorem for the multiplicative group of the field of $p$ elements (also known as Fermat's little theorem).
